# Find every same letters in a word

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a Hangman project that requires me to change characters "-" to "a to z". Since I'm learning how to code with C#, I have no clue how to do it.
I obviously need to use position because of the case where the word as duplicated letters (EX.: C **oo** kies)

Here's the code I developed, it makes my thing crashes and it's obviously incomplete.

```
    private void chkA_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (motRechercher.Contains("a"))
        {
            int indexDemotRechercher = motRechercher.IndexOf("a");
            int k = indexDemotRechercher;
            var StringBuilderOP = new StringBuilder(motRechercher);
            StringBuilderOP.Remove(indexDemotRechercher, indexDemotRechercher);
            StringBuilderOP.Insert(k, "A");
        }}
```

motRechercher is a STRING that I can use everywhere that I randomly pick from a list of 27 words. If this bother, it's a check-box and where I write the text is a Text-box(called txtMot).
Feel free to use other variables, I'll re-adapt after for my own comprehension. I would just like some explanation/examples to help my learning experience.

Here is the code of the randomiser if you really feel like this can help you understand[It works] :

```
        private void btnDemarrer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     Random rdn = new Random();
     int nbreAleatoire = rdn.Next(0, 27); 
     motRechercher = lesMots[nbreAleatoire];
            if (motRechercher.Length > 0)
            {
            String str = new String('-', motRechercher.Length);
            txtMot.Text = str;
            }
    }
```

QUESTION : How do I make a thing that detects duplicate and that will change the "-" to "a-z"?

Ask questions and I'll try to answer them if you think it's unclear.

Comment: Can you try using the String.Replace method to replace "-" with "a-z"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick sample... I have two strings... one for the hidden word the user does NOT see, and another for the one presented, using "-" or even "_" as place-holders for the actual characters.

I have a simple function "IsThereA" which expects a single letter as to the guess of a letter in the word.  I then just call for all the letters including a few random ones.  The function returns boolean so you can draw the hangman as each failure occurs.

In the "IsThereA" method, I am looking one character at a time for the guessed letter.  If found, I replace it by using substring instead of the "-".  So once updated, you can use the "WordUserCanSee" property however you need to.

This version doesn't do case-sensitive, but you can adjust as needed.

```
public class Hangman
{
    string HangmanWord = "cookies";
    string WordUserCanSee = "-------";

    public Hangman()
    {
        IsThereA("o");
        IsThereA("f");
        IsThereA("k");
        IsThereA("w");
        IsThereA("i");
        IsThereA("c");
        IsThereA("s");
        IsThereA("e");
    }


    public bool IsThereA(string guessLetter)
    {
        bool anyMatch = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < HangmanWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (HangmanWord.Substring(i, 1).Equals(guessLetter))
            {
                anyMatch = true;
                WordUserCanSee = WordUserCanSee.Substring(0, i) + guessLetter + WordUserCanSee.Substring(i + 1);
            }
        }

        return anyMatch;
    }
}
```

Comment: I must say, your code is really beautiful, and simple. Thank you sir.
Quick question about the IsThereA, can I replace it with a variable.Contain("LETTER")? I'll try it and see but seriously, thanks for the awnser!

Comment: @user3078728, you can change the function name to anything.. this was just my mental name for the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
motRechercher = motRechercher.Replace("-", "a-z");
```

Comment: Yeah it make sens, but it won't work because I need to use all the letters in the word.

Here's an exemple : Cookie.

It'll display : - - - - - - -

I need to turn that into Cookie, what you saying would turn it into either aaaaaaa, a-za-za-za-za-za-za-z or even abcdefg, depending on the writing you use...

ALSO you can't use txtMot(a text box).Replace...