# C# hangman, manipulating string

Tags: c#

I'm working on a hangman game, based on new tools and techniques of arrays, we haven't reached this part of the course-work, however I'm trying to get a head start.

Thus far I have this code (see below) I'm trying to display underscores per character in the zero array element (seven characters in total) then reveal a characters location if the guess it correct, I'm just looking for some insight in addition into my code, perhaps an article or even a code snippet that may shed some light on my dilemma.

EDIT: This is my new code, however, upon entering an 'a' for arizona, it only finds and prints the first 'a' how can I remedy this to find and print both a's to console?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Array_Arizona_Test
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string secretWord = "arizona";

        char[] secret = new char[secretWord.Length];

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Hangman!");

        Console.WriteLine("\nFirst Word.....\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < secret.Length; i++)
        {
            secret[i] = '_';
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < secret.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(secret[i] + " ");
        }

        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter your guess : ");
                char input = (Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray()[0]);

                if (secretWord[i] == input)
                {
                    secret[i] = input;

                    for (int x = 0; x < secret.Length; x++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(secret[x] + " ");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < secret.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(secret[i] + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
            count++;

        } while (count < 5);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: [Here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449517/find-every-same-letters-in-a-word) that can help you.

Comment: Please read the first two lines of the second paragraph, I'm trying to have the console reveal the location of the guess character if its correct, thus far, it prints far too many underscores to console.

Comment: Try updating the underscores array when the user guesses a character correctly `if (userInput == characters[x]) { underscores[x] = userInput }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should do

1. Create an array a and put dashes equal to the number of the letters in the word
2. Display that (step 1) to the user
3. When the user guess the right letter, put the letter in the right position in array a
4. Go to step 2

Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game)

Here is a code I just wrote

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        string secreteWord = "Arizona";

        //have a dash array equal to the number of the letters of the secret word
        char[] a = new char[secreteWord.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = '_';
        }

        // Tell the user the number of letters through the dashes
        for (int i = 0; i <a.Length ; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(a[i]+ "  ");
        }

        // ask the user to guess
        Console.WriteLine();

        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess letter");
            char input = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray()[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < secreteWord.Length; i++)
            {
                //if the user guessed right, replace the correct dash and display to the user
                if (secreteWord[i] == input)
                {
                    count++; //update the count to check when to exit
                    a[i] = input;  //here if the user guess correct, we replace the dash with the input

                   //now we display the dash array after it is modified
                    for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(a[j] + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        while (count < a.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("You guessed it right");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can simplify this? I'm only in my fourth month of procedural programming, we are not currently using var. If you could also include the explanation of how it updates from underscore to the guessed character I would greatly appreciate it. I'm not asking for a hand-out, I prefer to be able to understand it fully.

Comment: I have added some comments and if you dont get it, be specific and I will answer it

Comment: @RayneBlackham You need to have serious words with your tutor! Using `var` actually makes it quicker to write code; you just replace the type with `var`, e.g. `string Name = "John"` becomes `var Name = "John"`. Similarly, `int i = 0` is `var i = 0` and `StringBuilder SqlQuery = "SELECT * ..."` becomes `var SqlQuery = "SELECT * ..."`. It's a relatively new feature of C#, but it's a simple and good one!

Comment: @RayneBlackham and Danny : I would actually use var if I can easily see the data type from the right side of the =. Otherwise if you say var x= GetFoo(); it would be 'nonesense" but var str="This is string" makes more sense since immediately I can tell the data type

Comment: We have been informed we will be using vars, but not at this stage, we have been instructed to research arrays and experiment with them by creating a hangman game. Our tutor is not known for his clarity, hence why I come here for additional help, plus all the countless hours of reading, I learn better when I'm shown the syntax following an explanation of how that syntax works.

Comment: @RayneBlackham if it answers your questions, mark it as answer

Comment: If something is not clear let me know...I suggest you to read the wikipedia link I shared

Comment: I have one question, I think I actually understand 90%, however, one line eludes my understanding or at least a small portion of it.

char input = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray()[0];

What is the function of .ToCharArray()[0]; whats the explanation behind its function in relationed to the input.

Comment: @RayneBlackham  Console.ReadLine(), returns string , so I have to convert that to character array (ToCharArray()), so in case the user might type more than one character, I will only take the one upfront ([0])

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, now I understand it, I can add it to my arsenal of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to something like the following:

```
char[] guess = underscores.ToCharArray();
for (int x = 0; x < characters.Length; x++)
{
    if (userInput == characters[x])
    {
        guess[x] = userInput;
    }
}
Console.Write(guess);
```

You will also want to add another loop to allow the user guess multiple times at the same word.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I must change the string underscores to an array? then user the index to determine the position of the correctly guessed character and use your above code to update it?

Comment: Yes, you are correct - I have updated the code in my answer with a new variable